# Add prefix to zsh command prompt for any theme

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to add a prefix in the command prompt of ZSH **regardless of the chosen theme**. To be more precise, my current theme is `bureau` which can cause issues.

I tried several things. For example in the `.zshrc`:

```
PROMPT="prefix$PROMPT"
```

However the prefix shows up just before `$` and not at the very beginning (`{username} {path} {prefix}> $`).
My goal is to have:
`{prefix} {path} {prefix}>$`

Here my .zshrc

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
export TERM="xterm-256color"

ZSH_THEME="bureau"


plugins=(git gcloud)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh


autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
complete -o nospace -C /usr/bin/terraform terraform

PROMPT="prefix$PROMPT"
```

Comment: Why is this tagged bash? I don't see anything related to bash in this question.

Comment: Are you sure you are modifying the PROMPT variable after everyone else has modified it?

Comment: You'll need to give us the whole `.zshrc`.

Comment: No I'm not sure, that's why I am asking for help. I updated the post with my .zshrc. Thanks.

Comment: A given prompt theme doesn't necessarily define the prompt *once*; it can make use of various hooks to execute code each time the prompt is displayed, and that code can redefine `PROMPT` each time. Your static addition  of `prefix` in `.zshrc` isn't guaranteed to survive this process.

Comment: Short of defining a theme yourself, I don't think there is anyway to reliably do this.